# Approval workflow create a extra task

Tags: workflow, approval-process

When I start a specific Approval workflow, two tasks are created associated to the first user and a second task is created associated to a second user.

The workflow should not create two tasks associated with the first user, someone can help me with this?

Comment: WHich workflow are you using? Custom workflow?

Comment: I customize a Approval publish workflow 2010

Comment: But, the tasks are created in default mode.

Comment: Check if previous version of workflow is also running on the item.

Answer (score 0):

I found that in step "Pending Task" can not update the item, but I needed a flag that controls the moment when the second task is assigned. Put the action "update" in step "Task Completed" and it usually occurred